# Execution timeout (runtime error &h23) in roku

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

Right now I am working on an app, "Match 4" game which mimics the famous connect 4 game.

The problem we are facing is that the AI is build on MTD algorithm and code is perfectly tested. Its just sometimes machine gives, Execution timeout (runtime error &h23) while calculating best move.

Is there any way we can increase this time by some code?

I am writing my application in BrightScript. I am developing a Scene Graph application and error is on port 8089. My machine software version is: 7.2.0
Build: 4100.

It gives error.

Here is the error that prints:

```
Execution timeout (runtime error &h23) in pkg:/components/Connect4.brs(868)
```

Comment: What famous game is "Match 4"? If you mean "Four in a Row", that already exists on Roku - see https://channelstore.roku.com/details/4143/four-in-a-row - so suggest writing another one

Comment: See also http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=95858